# Datatables objects in a new row with json (ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, datatables

So far I've been able to use datatables with no problems displaying data with ajax from a json.
But today I ran into this problem. With Json having the following structure:

```
{
    "aaData": [
        {
            "id": 22,
            "name": "flavor 22",
            "flavorItem": [
                {
                    "hostSuffix": "google"
                },
                {
                    "hostSuffix": "yahoo"
                },
                {
                    "hostSuffix": "google"
                },
                {
                    "hostSuffix": "yahoo"
                },
                {
                    "hostSuffix": "google"
                },
                {
                    "hostSuffix": "yahoo"
                },
                {
                    "hostSuffix": "google"
                },
                {
                    "hostSuffix": "yahoo"
                },
                {
                    "hostSuffix": "google"
                },
                {
                    "hostSuffix": "yahoo"
                },
                {
                    "hostSuffix": "google"
                },
                {
                    "hostSuffix": "yahoo"
                },
                {
                    "hostSuffix": "google"
                },
                {
                    "hostSuffix": "yahoo"
                },
                {
                    "hostSuffix": "google"
                },
                {
                    "hostSuffix": "yahoo"
                },
                {
                    "hostSuffix": "google"
                },
                {
                    "hostSuffix": "yahoo"
                },
                {
                    "hostSuffix": "google"
                },
                {
                    "hostSuffix": "yahoo"
                },
                {
                    "hostSuffix": "google"
                },
                {
                    "hostSuffix": "yahoo"
                },
                {
                    "hostSuffix": "google"
                },
                {
                    "hostSuffix": "yahoo"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

When loaded into datatables this shows me all objects "hostSuffix" in the same row.
How I can show new lines for each object?

My script:

```
$("#example").dataTable({
    "serverSide": true,
    "searching": false,
    "aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 15, -1], [5, 10, 15, "All"]],
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "ajax": "<c:url value='/ajax/selectflavorEditor?id=22'/>",
    "columns": [
        {"data": "flavorItem[, ].hostSuffix"}

    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set `dataSrc` to point at the nested array `flavorItem` :

```js
$("#example").dataTable({
    "serverSide": true,
    "searching": false,
    "aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 15, -1], [5, 10, 15, "All"]],
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "ajax": {
        url: "<c:url value='/ajax/selectflavorEditor?id=22'/>",
        dataSrc: function(json) {
            return json['aaData'][0].flavorItem
        }
    },
    "columns": [
        {"data": "hostSuffix"}
    ]
});
```